# Activity displays if its task is in background, but there occurred calling startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have a main activity and some timer. When the timer is over, there occurred calling startActivityForResult. But if my task is in background then I want to see my new activity in background too. But instead of that my new activity appears on a display and override any task. Intents flags didn't help me. I tried to call moveTaskToBack after my new activity started, but if I just locked my phone then whole my task moveToBack when the timer is over.

Comment: sorry, but it´s absolute unclear what You are asking.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`, then this will move your task to the foreground. There isn't any way to prevent this.

What you can do is to delay calling `startActivityForResult()` if your app is in the background.